# How to use the HNC approximation to find the change in grand potential

Tags: density-functional-theory, statistical-thermodynamics, correlation-functions

I am reading Hansen and MacDonald's [Theory of Simple Liquids](https://www.elsevier.com/books/theory-of-simple-liquids/hansen/978-0-12-387032-2), and I am going through Integral Equation theories.

In section 4.3, they put forward the equation (4.3.14),

$${\small \Omega _{\phi} = \Omega _0 + \int \rho ^{(1)}(r) \phi (r) dr + kT\int \rho ^{(1)}(r) \ln \frac{\rho ^{(1)}(r)}{\rho _0} - \Delta \rho ^{(1)}(r) dr - \frac{1}{2}k_BT \int \int \Delta \rho ^{(1)}(r) c^{(2)}_0 (|r-r'|)\Delta \rho ^{(1)}(r')drdr'}$$

Then using the mass constraint, where $$\int \Delta \rho ^{(1)} (r)dr =0$$
Using the idea that particle $0$ provides an external field on all the other particles, he goes on to use $\phi(r) = u(0,r)$, and then uses the [HyperNetted Chain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypernetted-chain_equation) (HNC) approximation to state that
$$g(r) = \exp [-\beta u(r)]\exp [h(r)-c(r)]$$

Now, the authors make the jump and say that

$$\Omega = \Omega _0 + \frac{1}{2}\rho k_BT\int h(r)[h(r)-c(r)]dr - \rho k_BT\int c(r) dr$$

The quantity $\Delta \Omega = \Omega - \Omega _0$ is the change in grand potential arising from the additional particle at $0$, and using the [Ornstein-Zernike](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Zernike_equation) relation, which states that
$$h(r) = c(r) + \rho \int c(|r-r'|)h(r')dr'$$
for the homogeneous isotropic case.

I am using $\ln g(0,r) = -\beta u(0,r) + (h(r)-c(r))$, $\rho^{(1)}= \rho g(0,r)$, and $\Delta \rho^{(1)}= \rho h(0,r)$. However, I am not getting the result as they predict.

I think I am struggling with reducing the third term with the double integral, because I see that the first term with $\phi$ gets eliminated after I use $\ln g = -\beta u + h-c$, and $\phi(r) = u(0,r)$.

Any advice on how to go about this jump would be appreciated.

Comment: I gave +1 a while back, but I just came here to ask how this is going? Do you have any update based on anything you've learned about this question since asking it?

Comment: Any new developments? We try to go back through the unanswered questions every once in awhile to see if some aspects have been clarified or if the question is no longer of interest.

Comment: @Tyberius, no I have not made any new developments on this problem...

Comment: You would get more answers if you asked easier questions lol :)

Comment: @Wesley why is it so hard? What do you think megamance?